# No internet on Windows 7 virtual pc on Windows 7 with NAT configuration

Tags: windows-7, windows, microsoft-virtual-pc, internet-connection

I have installed Windows 7 on Microsoft virtual pc 2007 SP1 on Windows 7.
I configured networking adapter to use Shared networking (NAT).
But still I cannot access the internet from the virtual machine.

Note : Windows XP vms with the same settings (NAT) connects to the internet with no problem.

**Executing ipconfig results:**

Windows IP Configuration

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::14b4:b417:63ca:c363%11

IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.131.65

Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0

Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.131.254

Tunnel adapter isatap.{FED298E1-073A-4DEC-ABDA-B1DEBBBD66CE}:

Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected

Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with the integration feature enabled.  On your host machine, open up the properties for your network card and add a service called "Internet Protocol Verision 4".  In the virtual PC, configure the network to use the network card and it should work.

I just experienced this myself a couple days ago.  Here is the website I used to fix my problem. http://claytonj.wordpress.com/2007/02/02/connect-virtual-pc-to-internet/